# Initialization of population for genetic algorithm in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I randomly generated initial 10 population(let each of size n) of genetic algorithm as follows

```
for i = 1:10
    for j=1:n
        population(i,j)=randi([MinIntensity,MaxIntensity]);
    end
end
```

Assume that I have the individuals of one population.For example let the first population of size 10 is [100 110 120 130 140 150 160 170 180 190].Is it possible to generate the remaining 9 population such that the individuals are near to the first population?(It is for the quick convergence of genetic algorithm).Also each population is a grayscale image with intensity values represented in row major order.Hence the individuals should be in the range of 0 - 255.
Please help.Thanks in advance

Comment: Please use the word "individual" or equivalent if you mean a member of the population. This will clarify your question.

Comment: It's still pretty unclear... I know you are not saying it, but do you want to say that you have an individual that is a good first guess and then you want to generate the rest of the individuals in the population so that they are random but close to the first individual? (Each individual is a vector of 10 numbers in the range 0 to 255 inclusive.)